# CountVectorizer is resulting in error in python

Tags: python, countvectorizer

*I am trying to convert to vectors for a dataset that has two columns, review and sentiment. Below is the code.*

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/IMDB Dataset_SM.csv')
review = data['review']
review= [review] 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()
x= cv.fit_transform(review)
a=x.toarray()
col = cv.get_feature_names()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=col)
df
I am getting error :
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'.
```

Please help !!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
review=data['review'].values #this will create list
cv = countVectorizer()
x= cv.fit_transform(review)
```

[CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) accepts list of string.

In your code you are extracting `Series` when you are doing `review = data['review']`
 and then adding that series to list when you are doing `review= [review]`

Also, you need to check if your dataframe or series has non-string type element or `nan` elements.

Hope it helps.